# Not able to retrieve image and video through REST API which connects my front end

Tags: python, ajax, xmlhttprequest, blob, rest

I tried to get the video and the image from the user in a form, on clicking "submit", the video and image is converted to **Blob** and send to the backend. To my surprise, the blob file is not able to displayed and it returns NONE whenever i use

```
print(request.form.get('video'))
```

my demo.html :

```
<label>Choose video</label>
<input id="video" type="file" accept="video/*"><br><br>
<label>Choose thumbnail</label>
<input id="image" type="file" accept="image/*"><br><br>
<button onclick="submit(event)">Submit</button>

<script>
  function submit($event) {
  var formData = new FormData()

  videoFileType = document.getElementById("video").files[0].type
  imageFileType = document.getElementById("video").files[0].type

  videoBlob = new Blob([document.getElementById("video").files[0]], {type: videoFileType});
  imageBlob = new Blob([document.getElementById("image").files[0]], {type: imageFileType});

  formData.append('video', videoBlob)
  formData.append('image', imageBlob)

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log('Data `enter code here`submission successful.');
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:9000/abc", true);
  xhttp.send(formData);
}

</script>
```

main.py (on server side)

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask import request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

log_file = None

@app.route('/qaa' , methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('demo.html')

@app.route('/abc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getvalue():
    log_file = request.form
    print(request)
    video = request.form.get('video')


    if log_file is not None:
        print("**********")
        print(request.form)
        print(request.form.get('video'))
        
        # log_file variable will have all the information
        # from the JSON log file
        

    else:
        return "No data provided", 400



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9000)[enter image description here][1]
```

there is no error from the front end as it is sending the video and the image in binary.

please suggest the workaround or any edit required in the backend.

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s6tT.png)

Comment: Please learn how to take a screenshot. Please don't ever take pictures of your monitor with your phone.

Comment: @JamesZ my bad , i have added new image of  the output of my code